# Help proving a simple tautology $(p\land(p\to\lnot q))\to(\lnot q\lor p)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Specifically this  $$(p\land(p\to\lnot q))\to(\lnot q\lor p)$$-

spent a lot of time going down the wrong path

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work until line 6. is correct, but there is no Associative law as $a\lor(b\land c)\equiv(a\lor b)\land c$, so Complement law doesn't apply on line $7$, as when we see $a\lor b\land c$, the logical connective "$\land$" always connect first.

> \begin{align}
> \unicode{x2714}\hspace{6.3ex}~&\vdots\\
> \unicode{x2714}\hspace{2ex}6.~\equiv&\lnot p\lor (p\land q)\lor (\lnot q\lor p)\tag*{Double negation}\\
> \unicode{x2718}\hspace{2ex}7.~\equiv&\top\land q\lor(\lnot q\lor p)\tag*{Complement law}
> \end{align}

To fix this, we can apply Distributive law instead as following

\begin{align}
&\vdots\\
\equiv&\lnot p\lor (p\land q)\lor (\lnot q\lor p)\tag*{Line $6.$}\\
\equiv&(\lnot p\lor p)\land(\lnot p\lor q)\lor (\lnot q\lor p)\tag*{Distributive law}\\
\equiv&(\top\land(\lnot p\lor q))\lor (\lnot q\lor p)\tag*{Complement law}\\
\equiv&(\lnot p\lor q)\lor (\lnot q\lor p)\tag*{Identity law}\\
\equiv&\lnot p\lor (q\lor \lnot q)\lor p\tag*{Associative law}\\
\equiv&\lnot p\lor \top\lor p\tag*{Complement law}\\
\equiv&\top\tag*{Domination law}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

You were almost done, just two more steps are missing in your caluculation to reach tautologicalitly:

$
\vdots\\
\equiv q \lor (\neg q \lor p)\\
\equiv (q \lor \neg q) \lor p \quad\text{(associativity)}\\
\equiv \top \lor p \quad \text{(complement)}\\
\equiv \top \quad \text{(domination)}$

Comment: 'tautologicity'? is that an official word? If not, how about tautologicality?

Comment: I can't vouch for ever having seen either of them black on white, but your tautologicality actually sounds better.

Comment: Well, it has one more syllable, so it must be better :P

Answer (score 1):

The statement is valid. To see this, we can use a proof tree, like so

[image]

This was generated [here](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%20(p%E2%88%A7(p%E2%86%92%C2%ACq))%E2%86%92(%C2%ACq%E2%88%A8p))

Answer (score 1):

($p \Rightarrow \sim q $ )
$ \wedge p$
by Modus Ponens
$\Rightarrow   \sim q $
and by adition $\sim q \vee p $

Comment: Moreover $p\wedge (p\to\lnot q) \iff p\land\lnot q$